# Windows Outlook ribbon icons no longer have color

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

My Windows Outlook 365 menu bar used to look something like this:

[image]

As of yesterday, all of a sudden, it has started to look like this:

[image]

I have no idea what I did, or even if I did anything, but the icons in the menu bar have all changed. I've tried changing the Outlook theme. I've spent ~1 hour searching on Google. What happened and is it possible to change it back?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Thanks! I used the wrong link...corrected.

Comment: What [version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-version-of-outlook-do-i-have-b3a9568c-edb5-42b9-9825-d48d82b2257c) of Outlook do you have?

Comment: Is this from a corporate environment? It looks like you've gone from Office 2016 to something more like Office 365. Can you provide us with the version of Office you have? Take a screenshot of the `File > Office Account` screen?

Comment: it's my personal laptop. Under File -> Office Account it says "Subscription Product Microsoft Office 365." I've had this installed for about a year.

Comment: It definitely looks like you've been hit with the new Office 365 UI: https://www.engadget.com/2018/06/13/microsoft-office-ui-redesign-simpler-ribbon/ and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2018/06/13/power-and-simplicity-updates-to-the-office-365-user-experience/

Comment: As for changing it back, I imagine there's probably no way to do that considering you are Office 365 is an "always up-to-date" service.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelFrank. I've gotta run but I'll give you the answer if you want to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Your ribbon icons have a new look](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/your-ribbon-icons-have-a-new-look-c6bc4cd8-d151-41d3-8276-fc7c9975eb79)

That's the title of a recent Microsoft article relating to Office Insider versions of Office 365, which consists of exactly enough information to fit in one picture:

[image: New ribbon icons]

Since this is an Office Insiders feature, you might be able to leave the program to revert back to the old UI, however it might take a reinstall to force that.

Comment: I did so much searching but apparently I didn't use the right keywords but I didn't find anything like this. It is tough to search for help on Microsoft products.

Answer (score 0):

Disable updates, then run the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun"
officec2rclient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.10730.20102
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This answer could be much improved if you included some explanation of what this does and how that will solve OP's issue.

Comment: My guess is that this is a 'downgrade' to a previous version and then disabling updates will prevent it from upgrading once again. If the ribbon icons were super-important I might do something a bit drastic like this, but now I've grown used to them. Crazy, no? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like its implement on the Office 365. See here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Outlook-365-Ribbon-etc/td-p/267706